# How to merge the two audio files into a single audio file in android?

Tags: android, audio

I want to get two audio files as input, then merge them byte wise and save it as a single file.
In this code I have tried to do it in Java and it's working fine, but I don't know how to do it in android.

How to do it in android?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;

public class FileMixer {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
    Path path1 = Paths.get("C:\\Srini\\Wav\\welcome.wav");
    Path path2 = Paths.get("C:\\Srini\\Wav\\goodbye.wav"); 
    String path3 ="C:\\Srini\\Wav\\srini12.wav";
    File Newfilepath=new File(path3);

    byte[] byte1 = Files.readAllBytes(path1);
    byte[] byte2 = Files.readAllBytes(path2);
    byte[] out = new byte[byte1.length];
    for (int i=0; i<byte1.length; i++)
    {
        out[i] = (byte) ((byte1[i] + byte2[i]) >> 1);
    }

    InputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayInputStream(out);
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(byteArray);
    AudioSystem.write(ais, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE,Newfilepath);
    }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void mergeSongs(File mergedFile,File...mp3Files){
        FileInputStream fisToFinal = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(mergedFile);
            fisToFinal = new FileInputStream(mergedFile);
            for(File mp3File:mp3Files){
                if(!mp3File.exists())
                    continue;
                FileInputStream fisSong = new FileInputStream(mp3File);
                SequenceInputStream sis = new SequenceInputStream(fisToFinal, fisSong);
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                try {
                    for (int readNum; (readNum = fisSong.read(buf)) != -1;)
                        fos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
                } finally {
                    if(fisSong!=null){
                        fisSong.close();
                    }
                    if(sis!=null){
                        sis.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                if(fos!=null){
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
                }
                if(fisToFinal!=null){
                    fisToFinal.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It increase only size,,, but when i open it, only first audio is playing.

Comment: What issue you facing

Comment: I used this code but Unfortunately, It just increase the file size.

Comment: This code is just to merge two random files, but not to merge two audio files. To merge two audio files it's not enough to just append them byte to byte. There is the header and encoding involved. This answer is wrong and I think it shouldn't be accepted. 

This may work for wav files, althoug it won't be perfect because you will hear the 'clic' header between the two files. But definitively, this won't work for compressed files.

Comment: Yeah this solution shouldn't be accepted

Answer (score 3):

For combining two wav files use this code,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.SequenceInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;

public class WavAppender {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String wavFile1 = "D:\\wavOne.wav";
        String wavFile2 = "D:\\wavTwo.wav";

        try {
            AudioInputStream clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wavFile1));
            AudioInputStream clip2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wavFile2));

            AudioInputStream appendedFiles = 
                            new AudioInputStream(
                                new SequenceInputStream(clip1, clip2),     
                                clip1.getFormat(), 
                                clip1.getFrameLength() + clip2.getFrameLength());

            AudioSystem.write(appendedFiles, 
                            AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, 
                            new File("D:\\wavAppended.wav"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is too late. But still, someone might need a proper solution. That is why I am suggesting using [AudioMixer-android](https://github.com/rajib010/android_audio_mixer) library. You can also perform a lot of audio processing things.

Comment: I gave it a try. It's working but very very slow... Check the issues : https://github.com/ZeroOneZeroR/android_audio_mixer/issues