# android studio - moving float between activitys

Tags: android, android-activity, media-player

Hi I've tryed some ways to move float value between activitys with intent, but it's not working for me because the value restarts.

My code:

first activity:

```
Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(first.this, second.class);
                String s=Float.toString(selectedSpeed);
                myIntent1.putExtra("speed", s);
```

second activity:

```
String speed1=getIntent().getStringExtra("speed");
    float s=Float.parseFloat(speed1);
```

The value of the float is always 0 and the application have a compilation error in the secnd line in the "second activity".

Thanks to helpers!

Comment: post the full code and what is the error?

Comment: Are u sure you called the intent myIntent1? There seems to be no problem with your code. Also is the getIntent() called in onCreate()?

Comment: Yes, I've called the intnet "myintent1" and the getintent () called from the onCreate ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Activity 1

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putFloat("speed1", FloatVal);
yourIntent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(yourIntent);
```

Activity 2

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
float speed = bundle.getFloat("speed1");
```

Comment: Thanks man! 
Little question:
Why it's working with your way and not with mine?
Ty

Comment: And the last question for today:
There is a way to connect two audios into one?

Comment: If you want to add to audio files into one then you can check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/43650758/9626524