# Join two audio files in android

Tags: android, android-music-player

I wanted to join two audio files into a new file. I tried with MP4parser library it causes some issues, used the SquenceInputStream to combine two audio files, it increases the audio file size but plays only initial song.

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43650758/8775993

Checked with StackOverflow answers nothing worked.

Please suggest any solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can use ffmpeg for android. 
check this answer:](https://superuser.com/questions/1298891/ffmpeg-merge-multiple-audio-files-into-single-audio-file-with-android)

Comment: I tried the above link cmd it shows invalid argument, so let me know the working cmd line for the same. Thanks